# Referencing one method's output in another method of same class

Tags: java, class, variables

Here is my main method code:

```
public class WeightCalculatorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WeightCalculator weCa_init = new WeightCalculator(100);
        weCa_init.displayWeight();
        WeightCalculator weCa_def = new WeightCalculator();
        weCa_def.displayWeight();

        WeightCalculator weCa = new WeightCalculator(123);
        weCa.setWeight();
        weCa.displayWeight();
    }
}
```

Here is the method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WeightCalculator {

    private int weight = 0;
    private int hundreds;
    private int fifties;
    private int twenties;
    private int tens;
    private int fives;
    private int ones;
    private int total;
    private int[] result;

    // Default constructor
    public WeightCalculator()
    {

        weight=0;
        System.out.println();
    }   

    // Initial constructor
    public WeightCalculator(int w)
    {

        weight=w;
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void setWeight( ) {
           Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
           System.out.println("Life needs a balance");
           System.out.print("How many pounds does the item weight? ");
            weight = keyboard.nextInt();
         }// end inputWeight

        public int[] calculateBalanceWeights() {

            hundreds = weight/100;
            weight %= 100; 

            fifties = weight/50;
            weight %= 50; 

            twenties = weight/20;
            weight %= 20; 

            tens = weight/10;
            weight %= 10; 

            fives = weight/5;
            ones = weight %5;   

            total = hundreds+fifties+twenties+tens+fives+ones;

            int [] result = {hundreds, fifties, twenties, tens, fives, ones, total};

            return result; 

        }// end calcDays


        public void displayWeight() {
            System.out.println("You need "+calculateBalanceWeights()[6]+" weights in total:");
            System.out.println("   "+hundreds +" 100 lbs");
            System.out.println("   "+fifties +"  50 lbs");
            System.out.println("   "+twenties +"  20 lbs");
            System.out.println("   "+tens +"  10 lbs");
            System.out.println("   "+fives +"   5 lbs");
            System.out.println("   "+ones +"   1 lbs");
        }// end of display

}// end of class Time
```

My question is in this part of my code:

```
System.out.println("You need "+calculateBalanceWeights()[6]+" weights in total:");
```

why if I reference total it does not work - shows 0, while other variables can be referenced by name. And if I reference for other varibales in displayWeight as calculateBalanceWeights()[0] for hundreds it does not work?

I`m really confused how return variables are stored and referenced by other methods?

Aslo from the main method I can print the result array with

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(weCa.calculateBalanceWeights()));
```

But the results are wrong for the number entered?

Comment: Maybe a case of integer division i.e. with int variables `1 / 2 == 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get the problem. I guess your program is working correctly. I ran your code and got the following.

For the following part of your code:

```
WeightCalculator weCa_init = new WeightCalculator(100);
weCa_init.displayWeight();
```

Program outputs the following.

```
You need 1 weights in total:
   1 100 lbs
   0  50 lbs
   0  20 lbs
   0  10 lbs
   0   5 lbs
   0   1 lbs
```

The result contains `1 100 lbs` because of `new WeightCalculator(100)`.

For the following part of your code:

```
WeightCalculator weCa_def = new WeightCalculator();
weCa_def.displayWeight();
```

Program outputs the following.

```
You need 0 weights in total:
   0 100 lbs
   0  50 lbs
   0  20 lbs
   0  10 lbs
   0   5 lbs
   0   1 lbs
```

This time you initialized object with no value [`new WeightCalculator()`]. Thats why everything is zero here.

**Please note** that you have two constructor, one with parameter and one without parameter.

For the following part of your code:

```
WeightCalculator weCa = new WeightCalculator(123);
weCa.setWeight();
weCa.displayWeight();
```

Program outputs the following.

```
Life needs a balance
How many pounds does the item weight? 373
You need 8 weights in total:
   3 100 lbs
   1  50 lbs
   1  20 lbs
   0  10 lbs
   0   5 lbs
   3   1 lbs
```

This time you initialized object with a value [`new WeightCalculator(123)`] but after calling `setWeight()`, program gets `373` as user input and thus provide output accordingly.

So, what is the unexpected thing happening here?

---

**Update**

> Why if I reference `total` it does not work - shows 0, while other variables can be referenced by name.

You are getting zero as output when you use,

```
System.out.println("You need "+ total +" weights in total:");
```

inside `displayWeight()` function.

But your code works correctly when you write,

```
System.out.println("You need " + calculateBalanceWeights()[6] + " weights in total:");
```

This is obvious because a call to the function `calculateBalanceWeights()` updates all the variables - `hundreds, fifties, twenties, tens, fives, ones and total`.

When you simply use `total` inside `displayWeight()`, you are not making a call to the `calculateBalanceWeights()` function. As a result, no variable gets updated.

Do the following to achieve your desired behavior.

```
public void displayWeight() {
    calculateBalanceWeights();
    System.out.println("You need "+total+ " weights in total:");
    System.out.println("   "+hundreds +" 100 lbs");
    System.out.println("   "+fifties +"  50 lbs");
    System.out.println("   "+twenties +"  20 lbs");
    System.out.println("   "+tens +"  10 lbs");
    System.out.println("   "+fives +"   5 lbs");
    System.out.println("   "+ones +"   1 lbs");
}
```

This code snippet provides output correctly.

> If I reference for other varibales in displayWeight as `calculateBalanceWeights()[0]` for hundreds it does not work!

Because you can not call `calculateBalanceWeights()` many times. Once you call `calculateBalanceWeights()`, all the parameter values (`hundreds, fifties, twenties, tens, fives, ones and total`) gets updated.

So, just call `calculateBalanceWeights()` once and save the return value in a variable and then use it for printing results.

> Aslo from the main method I can print the result array with `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(weCa.calculateBalanceWeights()));` But the results are wrong for the number entered?

The numbers are not wrong. I checked it. For example, if user gives `373` as input,

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(weCa.calculateBalanceWeights()));
```

prints the following.

```
[3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 8]
```

Just compare it with what you are returning from `calculateBalanceWeights()` as given below.

```
int [] result = {hundreds, fifties, twenties, tens, fives, ones, total};
```

Hopefully, the updated answer will sort your confusion.

Comment: in the method   public void displayWeight() {
            System.out.println("You need "+calculateBalanceWeights()[6]+" weights in total:");
            System.out.println("   "+hundreds +" 100 lbs");
            System.out.println("   "+fifties +"  50 lbs");
            System.out.println("   "+twenties +"  20 lbs");
            System.out.println("   "+tens +"  10 lbs");
            System.out.println("   "+fives +"   5 lbs");
            System.out.println("   "+ones +"   1 lbs");

Comment: there i reference for total calculateBalanceWeights()[6] while other variables i reference by name. this is the only way it works in my code.